# How to get current stack size during node.js runtime?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to get current stack memory usage during node.js execution?

i.e. I'd like something along the lines of:

```
var stackInKb = global.getCurrentStackUsage();
```

Additionally, is there a way to set the stack memory usage in JavaScript? I know that this is possible when starting node.js, but I'd prefer to do it in JavaScript if possible.